# Get lesson url variable (liquid language) for Thinkific template

Tags: liquid

I have a site in the Thinkific LMS and there is a section on the course overview page that displays the Course curriculum. This is grabbed dynamically within the template code. My client would like to also link the title to the corresponding lesson.

I have found the code and added the link but I need to replace the # with a variable for the lesson page URL. Ive looked though all the support material and cant find that specific variable anywhere.

```
<section class="course-curriculum section-height__medium
    {% include 'section_utility_heading_alignment' %}" data-preview-item="course-curriculum">
    <div class="course-curriculum__container">
        {% include 'section_headings' %}
        <article class="section__content">
            <ul class="course-curriculum__chapter-list section__body">
                {% for chapter in page.course.chapters %}
                {% assign index = forloop.index + 1 %}
                <li class="course-curriculum__chapter">
                    {% if index < 10 %}
                    {% assign chapter_prefix = "0" %}
                    {% else %}
                    {% assign chapter_prefix = "" %}
                    {% endif %}
                    <div class="course-curriculum__chapter-content-wrapper">
                        <span class="course-curriculum__chapter-number">{{ index }}</span>
                        <header class="course-curriculum__chapter-header">
                            <h5 class="course-curriculum__chapter-title">{{ chapter.name }}</h5>
                            <span class="course-curriculum__chapter-header__toggle"><i tabindex="0" aria-label="toggle chapter content"></i></span>
                        </header>
                        <ul class="course-curriculum__chapter-content" id="chapter-{{ index + 1 }}">
                            {% for content in chapter.contents %}
                            <li>
                                {% if content.free %}
                                <a href="{{ page.course.links.enroll_free_trial }}" class="course-curriculum__chapter-lesson">
                                {% else %}
                                <span class="course-curriculum__chapter-lesson">
                                {% endif %}
                                <i class="{{ content.icon_css_class }}"></i><a href="#">{{ content.name }}</a>
                                {% if content.free %}
                                <span class="course-curriculum__chapter-lesson--free">{{ 'liquid.partials.course_landing_page_curriculum.label_free' | translate }}</span>
                                {% endif %}
                                {% if content.free %}
                                </a>
                                {% else %}
                                </span>
                                {% endif %}
                            </li>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </article>
    </div>
</section>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var $header = $('.course-curriculum .course-curriculum__chapter-header');
      {% if section.settings.show_collapsed %}
        $header.not(":eq(0)").each(function(k,v) {
          $(v).parents('.course-curriculum__chapter').addClass('course-curriculum__chapter--collapsed');
          $(v).next('.course-curriculum__chapter-content').hide();
        });
      {% endif %}
      $header.on('click keypress', function(e) {
        if (e.which === 13 || e.type === 'click') {
          e.stopPropagation();
          var $content = $(this).next('.course-curriculum__chapter-content');

          if($content.is(":visible")) {
            $content.slideUp(350).fadeOut(350);
            $(this).parents('.course-curriculum__chapter').addClass('course-curriculum__chapter--collapsed');
          }
          else {
            $content.slideDown(350).fadeIn(350);
            $(this).parents('.course-curriculum__chapter').removeClass('course-curriculum__chapter--collapsed');
          }
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

This is the area I need to add the variable:

```
<i class="{{ content.icon_css_class }}"></i><a href=" {{ ADD-VERIABLE-HERE }} ">{{ content.name }}</a>
```

Comment: Hey Dave - Aaron from Thinkific here. 
In addition to Jonathan's comment, I noticed that you are customizing a theme on Thinkific for a client. We can help to support you through that process! Check out our agencies & partners program here: https://www.thinkific.com/agencies/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jonathan here from the Thinkific product team.

The drop that you are looking for is `{{ content.take_course_url }}`. It's important to keep in mind, if a user clicks on this link and it is not part of the Free Trial, then it will land them back on the Course page and display a banner message of "You are not enrolled in this course".

If you would like to join our FB Group to connect with our community you should head on over to https://www.facebook.com/groups/thinkific/

Also, we hear you on the developer documentation. I can assure you we are already working on improving these areas to support you. Get in touch with us in the group and let Rob know I sent you ;)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks - exactly what I needed.